# Kotlin: Jackson Serialize an enums value

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, jackson

Using enum State:

```
enum class State(val desc: String) {
ACTIVE("In Use"),
INACTIVE("Not In Use")
}
```

and class Thing:

```
data class Thing {
  val name: String,
  val state: State
}
```

How would one use Jackson to serialize Thing such that
`"thing": { "name": "Thing's name", "state": "In Use"}`?

I know of `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` to annotate the State enum, but this results in `"thing": { "name": "Thing's name", "state": {"state": "ACTIVE", "desc": "IN USE"}` so isn't quite what I require.

Without any intervention the result is `"thing": { "name": "Thing's name", "state": "ACTIVE"}`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@JsonValue` annotation.

```kotlin
enum class State(@JsonValue val desc: String) {
    ACTIVE("In Use"),
    INACTIVE("Not In Use")
}
```